# Uniform distribution on the manifold: There exist a build-in solution?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, computational-geometry

In general, the problem is to generate many random points on the (high-dimensional, compact, smooth) manifold ~~ uniform distribution w.r.t. lebesgue measure. 
So, this is a common in the Monte-Carlo method, with many mathematical procedures and methods. But, if quickness matter: Does Mathematica have built-in solutions for it?

Comment: [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html)

Comment: RandomPoint works with _Region only. So there is a limitation of dimensionality

Comment: Example: `RandomPoint[
 ImplicitRegion[
  u^4 + v^8 + w^2 + x^2 + y^4 + z^6 <= 1, {u, v, w, x, y, z}], 10]` -- Counterexample?

Comment: Ah so. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  There must be a limitation to its robustness, since surely the algebra etc. can get too complicated.  When and if it doesn't work, a specific example will probably be needed to see if a workaround is possible.

Comment: I am afraid, this won't work for submanifolds of codimension >0. My guess is that  `RandomPoint` will bombard a bounding box of the `ImplicitRegion` with points and will pick only those that satisfy the conditions of the `ImplicitRegion`. With a region like `ImplicitRegion[
 u^4 + v^8 + w^2 + x^2 + y^4 + z^6 == 1, {u, v, w, x, y, z}]`, this may take a while to even get the first point...